# My External hard drive keeps unmounting on USB 3.0 using exfat

Tags: mount, usb-drive, external-hdd, debugging, exfat

I recently switched to Ubuntu from windows. I'm trying to move files from my external hard drive to my new Ubuntu installation but each time I try to copy over the files a few copy and then the drive is unmounted. The external hard drive is a new m.2 drive in an enclosure formatted in exfat. I'm using Ubuntu gnome and the version is Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS amd 64. The issue is reproducible on any usb 3.0 ports on my computer and seems to occur only during fast file transfers of larger files using exfat. I reformatted the drive to ext4 and it works fine even though it quickly slows from the expected speed of 400 MB/s to around 120 MB/s. Any help is greatly appreciated!

P.S. I am having the same issue with a flash drive that I know works well formatted in exfat.

The error message I get in the GUI is

> Error splicing file: Input/output error

System Info:
[Screenshot of System Information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wmZXB.png)

Here is the dmesg logs of the issue.

```
Jun 10 08:46:37 chase-System-Product-Name kernel: usb 3-4: reset high-speed USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd
Jun 10 08:46:38 chase-System-Product-Name kernel: [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000700] Failed to grab modeset ownership
Jun 10 08:50:36 chase-System-Product-Name kernel: usb 2-3: new SuperSpeed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
Jun 10 08:50:36 chase-System-Product-Name kernel: usb 2-3: New USB device found, idVendor=0bda, idProduct=9210, bcdDevice=20.01
Jun 10 08:50:36 chase-System-Product-Name kernel: usb 2-3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
Jun 10 08:50:36 chase-System-Product-Name kernel: usb 2-3: Product: Sabrent
Jun 10 08:50:36 chase-System-Product-Name kernel: usb 2-3: Manufacturer: Sabrent
Jun 10 08:50:36 chase-System-Product-Name kernel: usb 2-3: SerialNumber: 123400000012
Jun 10 08:50:36 chase-System-Product-Name kernel: usbcore: registered new interface driver usb-storage
Jun 10 08:50:37 chase-System-Product-Name kernel: scsi host6: uas
Jun 10 08:50:37 chase-System-Product-Name kernel: usbcore: registered new interface driver uas
Jun 10 08:50:37 chase-System-Product-Name kernel: scsi 6:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Sabrent                   1.00 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
Jun 10 08:50:37 chase-System-Product-Name kernel: sd 6:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
Jun 10 08:50:37 chase-System-Product-Name kernel: sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] 1953525168 512-byte logical blocks: (1.00 TB/932 GiB)
Jun 10 08:50:37 chase-System-Product-Name kernel: sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
Jun 10 08:50:37 chase-System-Product-Name kernel: sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 37 00 00 08
Jun 10 08:50:37 chase-System-Product-Name kernel: sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
Jun 10 08:50:37 chase-System-Product-Name kernel: sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Preferred minimum I/O size 512 bytes
Jun 10 08:50:37 chase-System-Product-Name kernel: sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Optimal transfer size 33553920 bytes
Jun 10 08:50:37 chase-System-Product-Name kernel:  sdb: sdb1 sdb2
Jun 10 08:50:37 chase-System-Product-Name kernel: sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI disk
Jun 10 08:50:37 chase-System-Product-Name kernel: exFAT-fs (sdb2): Volume was not properly unmounted. Some data may be corrupt. Please run fsck.
Jun 10 08:52:50 chase-System-Product-Name kernel: sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#28 uas_eh_abort_handler 0 uas-tag 4 inflight: CMD IN 
Jun 10 08:52:50 chase-System-Product-Name kernel: sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#28 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 37 17 4f 34 00 00 48 00
Jun 10 08:52:50 chase-System-Product-Name kernel: sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#24 uas_eh_abort_handler 0 uas-tag 3 inflight: CMD IN 
Jun 10 08:52:50 chase-System-Product-Name kernel: sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#24 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 37 17 4f 03 00 00 31 00
Jun 10 08:52:50 chase-System-Product-Name kernel: sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#21 uas_eh_abort_handler 0 uas-tag 2 inflight: CMD IN 
Jun 10 08:52:50 chase-System-Product-Name kernel: sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#21 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 37 17 4f 02 00 00 01 00
Jun 10 08:52:50 chase-System-Product-Name kernel: sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#20 uas_eh_abort_handler 0 uas-tag 1 inflight: CMD IN 
Jun 10 08:52:50 chase-System-Product-Name kernel: sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#20 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 37 17 4f 00 00 00 01 00
Jun 10 08:52:50 chase-System-Product-Name kernel: sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#14 uas_eh_abort_handler 0 uas-tag 18 inflight: CMD IN 
Jun 10 08:52:50 chase-System-Product-Name kernel: sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#14 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 37 17 4f 01 00 00 01 00
Jun 10 08:52:50 chase-System-Product-Name kernel: sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#13 uas_eh_abort_handler 0 uas-tag 17 inflight: CMD IN 
Jun 10 08:52:50 chase-System-Product-Name kernel: sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#13 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 37 17 48 1c 00 00 e4 00
Jun 10 08:52:50 chase-System-Product-Name kernel: sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#4 uas_eh_abort_handler 0 uas-tag 6 inflight: CMD IN 
Jun 10 08:52:50 chase-System-Product-Name kernel: sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#4 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 37 17 4f c1 00 00 3f 00
Jun 10 08:52:50 chase-System-Product-Name kernel: sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#3 uas_eh_abort_handler 0 uas-tag 5 inflight: CMD IN 
Jun 10 08:52:50 chase-System-Product-Name kernel: sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#3 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 37 17 4f 7c 00 00 45 00
Jun 10 08:52:50 chase-System-Product-Name kernel: scsi host6: uas_eh_device_reset_handler start
Jun 10 08:52:50 chase-System-Product-Name kernel: usb 2-3: reset SuperSpeed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
Jun 10 08:52:56 chase-System-Product-Name kernel: usb 2-3: device descriptor read/8, error -110
Jun 10 08:52:56 chase-System-Product-Name kernel: usb 2-3: reset SuperSpeed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
Jun 10 08:53:01 chase-System-Product-Name kernel: usb 2-3: device descriptor read/8, error -110
Jun 10 08:53:11 chase-System-Product-Name kernel: xhci_hcd 0000:01:00.0: Abort failed to stop command ring: -110
Jun 10 08:53:11 chase-System-Product-Name kernel: xhci_hcd 0000:01:00.0: xHCI host controller not responding, assume dead
Jun 10 08:53:11 chase-System-Product-Name kernel: xhci_hcd 0000:01:00.0: HC died; cleaning up
Jun 10 08:53:11 chase-System-Product-Name kernel: xhci_hcd 0000:01:00.0: Timeout while waiting for setup device command
Jun 10 08:53:11 chase-System-Product-Name kernel: usb 1-5: USB disconnect, device number 2
Jun 10 08:53:11 chase-System-Product-Name kernel: usb 1-6: USB disconnect, device number 3
Jun 10 08:53:11 chase-System-Product-Name kernel: usb 1-7: USB disconnect, device number 4
Jun 10 08:53:12 chase-System-Product-Name kernel: usb 2-3: device not accepting address 2, error -22
Jun 10 08:53:12 chase-System-Product-Name kernel: scsi host6: uas_eh_device_reset_handler FAILED err -19
Jun 10 08:53:12 chase-System-Product-Name kernel: sd 6:0:0:0: Device offlined - not ready after error recovery
Jun 10 08:53:12 chase-System-Product-Name kernel: sd 6:0:0:0: Device offlined - not ready after error recovery
Jun 10 08:53:12 chase-System-Product-Name kernel: sd 6:0:0:0: Device offlined - not ready after error recovery
Jun 10 08:53:12 chase-System-Product-Name kernel: sd 6:0:0:0: Device offlined - not ready after error recovery
Jun 10 08:53:12 chase-System-Product-Name kernel: sd 6:0:0:0: Device offlined - not ready after error recovery
Jun 10 08:53:12 chase-System-Product-Name kernel: sd 6:0:0:0: Device offlined - not ready after error recovery
Jun 10 08:53:12 chase-System-Product-Name kernel: sd 6:0:0:0: Device offlined - not ready after error recovery
Jun 10 08:53:12 chase-System-Product-Name kernel: sd 6:0:0:0: Device offlined - not ready after error recovery
Jun 10 08:53:12 chase-System-Product-Name kernel: usb 2-3: USB disconnect, device number 2
Jun 10 08:53:12 chase-System-Product-Name kernel: sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#3 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_TIME_OUT driverbyte=DRIVER_OK cmd_age=52s
Jun 10 08:53:12 chase-System-Product-Name kernel: sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#3 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 37 17 4f 7c 00 00 45 00
Jun 10 08:53:12 chase-System-Product-Name kernel: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 924274556 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x80700 phys_seg 69 prio class 0
Jun 10 08:53:12 chase-System-Product-Name kernel: sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#4 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_TIME_OUT driverbyte=DRIVER_OK cmd_age=52s
Jun 10 08:53:12 chase-System-Product-Name kernel: sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#4 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 37 17 4f c1 00 00 3f 00
Jun 10 08:53:12 chase-System-Product-Name kernel: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 924274625 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x80700 phys_seg 63 prio class 0
Jun 10 08:53:12 chase-System-Product-Name kernel: sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#13 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_TIME_OUT driverbyte=DRIVER_OK cmd_age=52s
Jun 10 08:53:12 chase-System-Product-Name kernel: sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#13 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 37 17 48 1c 00 00 e4 00
Jun 10 08:53:12 chase-System-Product-Name kernel: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 924272668 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x80700 phys_seg 228 prio class 0
Jun 10 08:53:12 chase-System-Product-Name kernel: sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#14 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_TIME_OUT driverbyte=DRIVER_OK cmd_age=52s
Jun 10 08:53:12 chase-System-Product-Name kernel: sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#14 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 37 17 4f 01 00 00 01 00
Jun 10 08:53:12 chase-System-Product-Name kernel: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 924274433 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x80700 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
Jun 10 08:53:12 chase-System-Product-Name kernel: device offline error, dev sdb, sector 924274484 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x80700 phys_seg 72 prio class 0
Jun 10 08:53:12 chase-System-Product-Name kernel: device offline error, dev sdb, sector 924274435 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x80700 phys_seg 49 prio class 0
Jun 10 08:53:12 chase-System-Product-Name kernel: device offline error, dev sdb, sector 924274434 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x80700 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
Jun 10 08:53:12 chase-System-Product-Name kernel: device offline error, dev sdb, sector 924274432 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x80700 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
Jun 10 08:53:12 chase-System-Product-Name kernel: device offline error, dev sdb, sector 924274557 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x80000 phys_seg 68 prio class 0
Jun 10 08:53:12 chase-System-Product-Name kernel: device offline error, dev sdb, sector 924274626 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x80000 phys_seg 62 prio class 0
Jun 10 08:53:12 chase-System-Product-Name kernel: sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Synchronizing SCSI cache
Jun 10 08:53:12 chase-System-Product-Name kernel: sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Synchronize Cache(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_ERROR driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
Jun 10 09:02:20 chase-System-Product-Name kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1686402140.176:75): apparmor="DENIED" operation="capable" class="cap" profile="/snap/snapd/19361/usr/lib/snapd/snap-confine" pid=5680 com>
Jun 10 09:02:20 chase-System-Product-Name kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1686402140.176:76): apparmor="DENIED" operation="capable" class="cap" profile="/snap/snapd/19361/usr/lib/snapd/snap-confine" pid=5680 com>
Jun 10 09:02:20 chase-System-Product-Name kernel: audit: type=1326 audit(1686402140.248:77): auid=1000 uid=1000 gid=1000 ses=3 subj=snap.snap-store.ubuntu-software pid=5680 comm="snap-store" exe="/snap/snap-sto>
Jun 10 09:02:20 chase-System-Product-Name kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1686402140.352:78): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" class="file" profile="snap.snap-store.ubuntu-software" name="/etc/pulse/client.con>
Jun 10 09:02:20 chase-System-Product-Name kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1686402140.352:79): apparmor="DENIED" operation="connect" class="file" profile="snap.snap-store.ubuntu-software" name="/run/user/1000/pul>
Jun 10 09:02:22 chase-System-Product-Name kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1686402142.280:80): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" class="file" profile="snap.snap-store.ubuntu-software" name="/etc/pulse/client.con>
Jun 10 09:02:22 chase-System-Product-Name kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1686402142.280:81): apparmor="DENIED" operation="connect" class="file" profile="snap.snap-store.ubuntu-software" name="/run/user/1000/pul>
Jun 10 09:02:22 chase-System-Product-Name kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1686402142.376:82): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" class="file" profile="snap.snap-store.ubuntu-software" name="/etc/pulse/client.con>
Jun 10 09:02:22 chase-System-Product-Name kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1686402142.376:83): apparmor="DENIED" operation="connect" class="file" profile="snap.snap-store.ubuntu-software" name="/run/user/1000/pul>
Jun 10 09:02:22 chase-System-Product-Name kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1686402142.376:84): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" class="file" profile="snap.snap-store.ubuntu-software" name="/etc/pulse/client.con>
```

Comment: version/distro of Ubuntu? [edit] in to your question

Comment: Anything in the output of `journalctl --dmesg` which might help to identify the problem?

Comment: I added my version of Ubuntu to the post as well as the dmesg logs you asked for. I wasn't sure how to attach a file so I just copied and pasted it to the end of my post.

Comment: The last entry at 08:50:37 suggests running fsck - did you try that as a start?

Comment: I tried running fsck but it didn't fix the issue.

Comment: Is the external drive powered via USB or does it have a different power supply?

Comment: It's powered via USB. I found our that the uas driver is the cause of the issue but disabling it makes mu usb 3.0 ports useless.

Comment: I followed the suggested answer here but it didn't work. It just disabled uas. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1266804/blacklist-uas-drivers-in-kernel

Comment: Is there a way that I can replace the uas driver with an older version that works? I can't use any of my USB 3.0 ports right now and the USB 2.0 Is averaging 40MB/s.